# CSS position fixed inside overflow-y:scroll

Tags: html, css

i have a problem for getting `DIV` with `position:fixed;` stick into DIV that had `overflow-y:scroll;`

check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1d5asvo7/

why `position:fixed` not stick inside that `DIV` with `overflow-y:scroll` ?

why `position:fixed` refer to `window`?

what's wrong with my code?
how to get this things work?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `width: inherit` for `fixed` element to get `width` from `parent`

```css
#scrollable {width:400px; height:100%; overflow-y:scroll; }
#fixed {
    width: inherit;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: red;
}
#content {width:100%; height:200px; }
```

```html
<div id="scrollable">
  <div id="fixed">
  this is fixed
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content v this is contentv v this is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content v this is contentv v this is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content this is content v this is contentv v this is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to avoid fixed element covers scroll bar?

Comment: @IgorJanković you can add some right padding to `#scrollable` or use `z-index: -1;` for `#fixed` or in worst way, reduce with of fixed div manually.